# Fluent API, Annotations and EF 4.1

Tags: entity-framework, data-annotations, fluent-interface

Would somebody please guide me towards links that explain Fluent API and Annotations when using EF 4.1 code first please?  The more in depth, the better.

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May issue of [MSDN magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh126815.aspx) contains article about EF 4.1. For further information check these blogs:

- [ADO.NET team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/)
- [Morteza Manavi's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/default.aspx)
- [Julie Lerman's Blog](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/)

You can also check [this video](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=ef41-code-first) but for that you need a subscription ($29 per month).

Almost everything can be found on Stack Overflow ;)

[code-first](/questions/tagged/code-first) [ef-code-first](/questions/tagged/ef-code-first) [entity-framework-4.1](/questions/tagged/entity-framework-4.1) [dataannotations](/questions/tagged/dataannotations)

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723 has many tutorials on Entity Framework 4.1

Fluent API : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh272551

Data Annotations : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958